# How to change the color of kendo mobile drawer

Tags: ios, css, kendo-mobile

I am using kendo angular mobile Drawer. I want to change the color of the drawer. How do I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In this post I will show you how we can put a background color in Kendo UI Mobile view. Let us suppose that we got following view.**

```
<div id="homeview” data-role=“view”
                   data-title=“home view”
                   data-layout=“mobile-home”>
       <p>home view</p>
</div>
```

**There may be requirement when you will have to change background color of this view. You can change that using CSS as following**

```
<style scoped>

      #homeview
      .km-content
      {
         background: red;
      } 

</style>
```

**You will have to put this CSS on the page.**